# how to retrieve URL into GSP

Tags: html, grails

i am trying to show a content in iframe..it works at localhost

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]"/></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="body">

        <iframe style="width: 100%;min-height: 400px;height: 600px" src="https://www.google.com" />

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

but when i build a war and deploy it to server...that page was blank?

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Facebook doesn't allow it:

```
curl -v https://www.facebook.com
...
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
...
```

With `DENY` value:

> The page cannot be displayed in a frame, regardless of the site
>   attempting to do so.

Google and many other sites have similar configuration, so please check for header. Also, you could open Chrome Developer Console, and check for errors

See docs for this header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

Comment: provide url of this site, and make sure it doesn't have such header

Comment: ok, i see. google.com have `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`, so not going to work too

Comment: http://free.7m.cn/live.aspx?mark=en&TimeZone=%2B0700&wordAd=Pasang%20Taruhan%20Bola&cpageBgColor=000000&wadurl=http://rajabola.com&width=730&tableFontSize=12&cborderColor=00CC00&ctdColor1=ffffff&ctdColor2=dddddd&clinkColor=009900&cdateFontColor=00CC00&cdateBgColor=000000&scoreFontSize=12&cteamFontColor=000000&cgoalFontColor=00FF00&cgoalBgColor=000000&cremarkFontColor=00FF00&cremarkBgColor=000000&Skins=3&teamWeight=400&scoreWeight=700&goalWeight=700&fontWeight=700&DSTbox=

Comment: yes, it works for `free.7m.cn`. just tried to put it into your example, works perfectly

Comment: no..what i get was a blank iframe after deploy it...but it run in iframe if i run at localhost

Comment: what do you get in Chrome (Firefox?) Developer Console then? any errors?

Comment: even in Developer Console, no messages at all?

Comment: its look like..iam using https...but if ichange it to http..my code is working..but it cannot display if i am using https